# Installing Anaconda for Linux

Tags: linux, anaconda

I am trying to install Anaconda for Linux (Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela, 14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr).

I see a warning:

WARNING:
    Machine does not appear to be ppc64le.  This software was sepicically
    build for POWER8 running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
    Are sure you want to continue the installation? [yes|no]

What should I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is the machine a power8 or x86?  More than likely you have an x86 cpu so you need to install that version of Anaconda. [Anaconda Repo](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/). You can use the command `uname -a` from the command line to print the kernel version.  Normally you would see something in the output that says like "x86_64".

As for the anaconda versions, notice the differences between these two file names.

- Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
- Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-ppc64le.sh

:::EDIT:::
Based on the your warning "WARNING: Machine does not appear to be ppc64le.", it sounds like you have an x86 cpu. To be sure, run the command `uname -a`.

Comment: when I use uname -a I see follow "Linux xhome 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

Comment: so, I need to install Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh or Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-ppc64le.sh ???

Comment: I think Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh. Yes?

Comment: Yes, install the x86 version.  Remember that Anaconda2 is Python2.7 and Anaconda3 is Python3.x