# Anaconda installation

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I'm trying to install anaconda on a remote server. It's a 64 bit machine running ubunto 16.04.2 LTS . I want to use python 2.7, so I download the correspondent file from the anaconda website. However, when I start installing I get the following warning

```
WARNING:
    Machine does not appear to be ppc64le.  This software was sepicically
    build for POWER8 running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
    Are sure you want to continue the installation?
```

EDIT: After posting I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434936/installing-anaconda-for-linux?rq=1). I run

```
uname -a
```

and the output was

```
Linux elephant01a 4.4.0-87-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 18 12:55:35 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There is a "X86_64" there, so I think the advice from @16num don't apply where.

What does this mean? Should I processed anyway?

Comment: It seems you're not using the proper version of Anaconda. Make sure you select the appropriate Anaconda binary (x86_64) and not PPC. If unsure of the version you're using, go to the anaconda website and select the binary to download manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, but in order to help other I will post it here. There is a file called Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh refereed also in the comments of the linked post.

I think the main problem is with the download page of anacond itself, as this file is not the one we get by selecting python 2.7 in Ubunto 64 bits.